# How to get SQL result in a temp table and run another script on temp table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to split one column into multiple columns by delimiters. So I have written following script and its working fine.

```
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(50)
SET @delimiter=',' 
;WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT

        [ODC_Number],
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([ODC_Number], @delimiter , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) 
        AS [Employee Name XML]
    FROM  tbl_ODC_Number 
)
SELECT

     [ODC_Number] as ODC_Number,
     [Employee Name XML].value('/M[1]', 'varchar(50)') As [ODC_Number1],
     [Employee Name XML].value('/M[2]', 'varchar(50)') As [ODC_Number2],
     [Employee Name XML].value('/M[3]', 'varchar(50)') As [ODC_Number3]

FROM CTE
```

Now I need to know how to get this result in a temp table and run a following script to check format of each new column to make sure each column data have right format:

Format:

```
ODC-XXXX-XXX-XXXXXX   ODC-2018-076-895689
```

- Each value length should be 19 digits
- Start only with ODC
- Check is there are any other delimiters except commas

So I've written following code (this needs to be written for each column)

```
Select * from TEMPDB
Where

Len (ODC_Number1) < '19' or
ODC_Number1 not like '%[CRI]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' or
ODC_Number1  like '%[CRI]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[CRI]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' or
ODC_Number1 like '%[%*$#@;&/.\ ]%' or
ODC_Number1 not like '[CRI]%' or
ODC_Number1 like '%-CRI%'
```

I've written those two scripts but don't know how to combine them?

Comment: This appears to be [tag:sql-server] syntax, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

To get your data into a temp table simply do a `SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM CTE`

```
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(50)
SET @delimiter=',' 
;WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT

        [ODC_Number],
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([ODC_Number], @delimiter , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) 
        AS [Employee Name XML]
    FROM  tbl_ODC_Number 
)
SELECT

     [ODC_Number] as ODC_Number,
     [Employee Name XML].value('/M[1]', 'varchar(50)') As [ODC_Number1],
     [Employee Name XML].value('/M[2]', 'varchar(50)') As [ODC_Number2],
     [Employee Name XML].value('/M[3]', 'varchar(50)') As [ODC_Number3]

       INTO #Temp
FROM CTE
```

Now for your checks execute your code for each column separated with `OR`

```
Select * 
from #Temp
Where
(
Len (ODC_Number1) < '19' or
ODC_Number1 not like '%[CRI]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' or
ODC_Number1  like '%[CRI]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[CRI]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' or
ODC_Number1 like '%[%*$#@;&/.\ ]%' or
ODC_Number1 not like '[CRI]%' or
ODC_Number1 like '%-CRI%'
)
OR 
(
Len (ODC_Number2) < '19' or
ODC_Number2 not like '%[CRI]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' or
ODC_Number2  like '%[CRI]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[CRI]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' or
ODC_Number2 like '%[%*$#@;&/.\ ]%' or
ODC_Number2 not like '[CRI]%' or
ODC_Number2 like '%-CRI%'
)
OR 
(...... You get the idea....
```

Comment: Dear Ali
You are awesome, thank you so much for your great help. I have couple of more questions if you can kindly answer:
- There are number of "NULL" values in each column, when I execute the checks its returning all of those NULL's as well. Can you please help me to add a piece of code to exclude these NULL's from result
- My second concern is as I am doing same check for each column, is there any way I can apply the check for all of the columns rather than separately for each column?
I greatly appreciate your kind assistance on this and thank you very much for everything.

Comment: Dear Ali
This is how it's returning null values, that's what I wanted to get rid of… I only wanted it to return if there are any data which are satisfied with the codes:
ODC_Number1 ODC_Number2 ODC_Number3
ODC 2018-009-000896 NULL NULL
ODC-2014-004-006723 NULL NULL
ODC-2014-044-002881 ODC-2016-009-011094 NULL
ODC-2015-070-003995 ODC-2015-070-003970 NULL NULL
ODC-2015-070-000521 NULL NULL
ODC-2015-070-003995 ODC-2015-070-003970 NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL
ODC-2016-004-009159 NULL NULL
ODC-2016-009-011047 ODC-2016-009-011094 NULL

Thanks for your help